# Firebase Facebook login in Flutter working on Android but throws 'App is not active' error on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, facebook-login

I am developing a Flutter app that incorporates Facebook login using Firebase Authentication. The Facebook login functionality works perfectly fine on Android devices, but when users try to log in using Facebook on iOS devices, they encounter an error stating "App is not active." I am seeking assistance in resolving this issue.

Here's the relevant code snippet I'm using for Facebook login in my Flutter app:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';

import 'auth_util.dart';

Future<UserCredential> facebookSignIn() async {
  if (kIsWeb) {
    FacebookAuthProvider facebookProvider = FacebookAuthProvider();

    facebookProvider.addScope('email');
    facebookProvider.setCustomParameters({
      'display': 'popup',
    });

    // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(facebookProvider);
  }

  // Trigger the sign-in flow
  final LoginResult loginToken = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
  final AccessToken? result = loginToken.accessToken;

  // Create a credential from the access token
  final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
      FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result!.token);

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  return FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
}

Future<User?> signInWithFacebook(BuildContext context) =>
    signInOrCreateAccount(context, facebookSignIn, 'FACEBOOK');
```